# How to pick the tuple key with fewer tuple elements in a dictionary if values are equal

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with tuple keys and numbers as values.

```
max_count_dict = {(2,4):1, (4,):1}
```

Now, I want to return the key with fewer tuple elements, in this case `(4,)` if the values are equal.
If they are not equal, it should return the one with the maximum count.

I got the part to find the max part using the below code:

```
max_count_key = max(max_count_dict, key=max_count_dict.get)
```

I'm not sure how to implement the part for equal values.

Comment: _if the values are equal_ Do you want to do this for ANY items in the dict where the values are equal?  Or only for a given value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
max_count_dict = {(2, 4): 1, (4,): 1}

max_count_key = max(max_count_dict, key=lambda k: (max_count_dict[k], -len(k)))
print(max_count_key)
```

Prints:

```
(4,)
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrej. Is there a way to compare values as well? I need to return this if the values are equal.

Comment: @Faren Maybe I don't understand. This will return the **maximum** value, but if you have multiple equal maximum values (`1` in your example), it will pick the key with minimum count (`(4, )` in this case).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I thought I should have an if for equal ones. It works perfectly, I appreciate it